# How can I configure Intellij to custom code generation location?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea, getter, getter-setter

By default, Intellij generates code in the location by nearest.

For example, when generating getter method, it makes the getter method nearby the caret.

It's not convenient.

So, if I want to generate the getter method at the bottom of current file, how can I customize the location?

Answer (score 4):

IDEA 12 will support it out of the box, it will bundle the [Rearranger](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=173) plug-in which we rewrote from the ground up.

Not sure if the old plug-in for IDEA 11 supports it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Rearranger looks nice. Is it possible for it to only affect the generated code, or must it rearrange the entire file? (to minimize changes to previously committed code)